# How can I remove all default padding from EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview, padding

I am using an `EditText` and it always adds a bit of padding in my text to both left and right.
Adding `android:includeFontPadding="false"` did not help and using negative `android:layout_marginLeft` or `android:layout_marginRight` just makes the `EditText` "expand".
How can I strip all padding from the `EditText` that is being added by default?

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="roboto-regular"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size"
            android:textColor="@color/color"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:editable="false"

            />
```

Comment: post your xml please

Comment: Some, if not all, of that is coming from the background, particularly if the background is a nine-patch PNG file.

Comment: @CommonsWare:I am not using any background. Please see update in OP

Comment: Set: `android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        tools:text="test test"`

Comment: "I am not using any background" -- yes, you are. You are not *changing* the background. Hence, you are getting the standard background for whatever theme you are using.

Comment: @dieter_h:Using `android:padding="0dp"` does remove the padding but using `android:background="@null"` also removes the line bellow that indicates to the user that this is an area to type. Is there a way to move the line as well to match the padding removed?

Comment: See how to look like EditText background 9 patch drawable. http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: I don't think any such type possibilities in edittext some thing is happened with your image or any thing else.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To remove the padding on the left and right of the `EditText`, you can use the following:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    ... />
```

Comment: So easy, so it just has some non-zero padding by default.

Comment: This will remove the padding for the text, but the line beneath it will still have a padding, which makes it look bad (at least in Android 8).

Comment: Try adding android:paddingBottom="0dp" (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:paddingBottom)

Comment: Franco's comment is right. This answer is not valid for me.

Answer (score 11):

If you also want to remove underline padding add negative margin:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
    ... />
```

Comment: Sometimes negative margin isn't a got idea. I faced problems with context popup menu appearance on some Samsung devices

Answer (score 1):

Indeed EditText has its own drawable padding which remains even after setting all paddings/margins to zero in xml.
To fully remove padding from EditText you have to remove it from its drawable which in fact is InsetDrawable.

You can cast your drawable to `InsetDrawable`, get the original drawable via `getDrawable()` method. That original drawable doesn't have additional spacing at all and you can set it as a new background via `setBackground()` to your `EditText` widget.

```
val etRemovedSpacingAllSides = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etRemovedSpacingAllSides)
if (etRemovedSpacingAllSides.background is InsetDrawable) {
    val insetDrawable = etRemovedSpacingAllSides.background as InsetDrawable
    val originalDrawable = insetDrawable.drawable!!
    etRemovedSpacingAllSides.background = originalDrawable
}
```

But you'd rather want it to save its top and bottom insets, because otherwise `EditText` looks ugly.

[image]

To preserve horizontal spacing you have to subtract original padding dimensions from inset drawable padding dimensions. I assume that padding is calculated by summing original drawable padding and inset drawable insets. So to retrieve only insets you have to perform subtraction.

Here is full example (Corresponds to "removed spacing only horizontal" `EditText` on picture):

```
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etRemovedSpacing)
if (editText.background is InsetDrawable) {
    val insetDrawable = editText.background as InsetDrawable
    val originalDrawable = insetDrawable.drawable!!
    val insetDrawablePadding = Rect()
    insetDrawable.getPadding(insetDrawablePadding)
    val originalDrawablePadding = Rect()
    originalDrawable.getPadding(originalDrawablePadding)

    // We subtract original padding dimensions from inset drawable padding dimensions.
    // We assume that padding is calculated by summing original drawable padding
    // and inset drawable insets. So to retrieve only insets we have to perform subtraction
    val insetDrawableInsets = Rect(
            insetDrawablePadding.left - originalDrawablePadding.left,
            insetDrawablePadding.top - originalDrawablePadding.top,
            insetDrawablePadding.right - originalDrawablePadding.right,
            insetDrawablePadding.bottom - originalDrawablePadding.bottom)
    // Remove side spacing from editText background to make it fit fully into layout width
    editText.background = InsetDrawable(
            originalDrawable,
            0, insetDrawablePadding.top, 0, insetDrawableInsets.bottom)
}
```

Comment: how can you do this with xml?

Comment: @lan I think there is no way to do this in pure xml