# EditText is cut off with white space

Tags: android, xml

I have textfield - text view in relative layout with rounded rectangle. It looks fine until I try to change textview to edit text. After it, text of EditText view is cutted of. Well, I try to change height to wrap_content, it fixes the problem of cutting, but the rounded rectangle becomes much higher than with textView although EditText height seems like only half of the rectangle outside. How can I remove these spaces below and above the real visible EditText? Any manipulations with margins/paddings don't help me.

EditText with wrap_content height:

[image: EditText with wrap_content height]

EditText with 30dp height:

[image: EditText with 30dp height]

TextView with 30dp height:

[image: TextView with 30dp height]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/token_input_layout_outside"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_divider"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingVertical="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/top_divider"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_divider">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/token_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/counter_monitor_width"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_background_3"
        android:gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/token_input"
            android:layout_width="85sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:maxLength="5"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:hint="Input"
            android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
            </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe check this answer, it looks like it is solving your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67233417/12761873

Comment: @JTODR Thank you, this is actually useful answer. But EditText was still about 20% higher than same TextView because of underline with some space between it and text itself. So I came up with: Background="@null". I didn't expect that this will also remove all paddings. That's what don't need any non-xml code and totally fixed my problem. Maybe it will not be so suitable for others who need to remain underline but for me it's best solution

Answer (score 0):

30dp is a small height for your textSize; so you can do it in two different ways:

1. make edit text wrap_content:

---

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/token_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/counter_monitor_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_background_3"
            android:gravity="center">

            <EditText
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/token_input"
                android:layout_width="85sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:hint="Input"
                android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
            </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

---

2. change height size:

---

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/token_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/counter_monitor_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_background_3"
            android:gravity="center">

            <EditText
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/token_input"
                android:layout_width="85sp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:hint="Input"
                android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
            </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

---

Comment: That's exactly what I showed in screenshot "EditText with 30dp height" - EditText becomes cut off with code like this. So, as already said in the post comments, Background = "@null" fixes this code